# Navbar and slider layers difficulty

Tags: javascript

I'm having difficulty getting a navbar and a slider to work together. The problem is when it is in mobile view.  If you click on the menu icon the menu item slide in from the side but the top ones are appearing stacked underneath the slideshow.

Here is a sample of it posted on my domain test page. http://ecfleming.com/test/index.html

I have tried using a `z-index` in the CSS as well as few other things. I suspect it might be something in the JavaScript, but I can not figure out what. Does anyone have any ideas of what I can try to fix this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself preferably in a runnable [Stack Snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It also very helpful to show in your Question an expected result, and quote any (exact) errors you are getting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a quick fix, you can add `.cycle-slideshow { z-index:-1 }`

Comment: SUCCESS.  Thank you.  For some reason I didn't think of negative numbers when I tried the z-index idea the first time.

Answer (score -1):

Try not to hard code the height value of div id="header"

Fix the mobile view by removing the height 185px.